# Is there a purely charisma-based divine caster?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, magic, spellcasting

Do we have a class like oracle from pathfinder but for D&D 3.5? The only one I can find is the favored soul from complete divine, but it's wisdom based, and I would love to have one charisma based.

Comment: Favored soul is actually split between Wisdom (DCs) and Charisma (minimum to learn and bonus spells).

Answer (score 10):

To quote the [3.5 Caster Classes Index](https://minmaxforum.com/index.php?topic=8768.0):

- Favored Soul (- spontaneous divine) cha w/wis DCs [cleric list]
- Shugenja (- spontaneous divine) cha [own list]

So if Oracle's out and you don't want the Wis DCs from Favored Soul, then [Shugenja](https://www.realmshelps.net/charbuild/classes/alternate/shugenja.shtml) seems to be your best bet. It's a full caster with [its own list](https://www.realmshelps.net/magic/OAspellbooks/shugenja), which is somewhat underwhelming<strike>, but they DO get access to 9th level spells at character level 16, so there's that</strike>.

Whoops! Complete Divine errata:

> **Page 11: Shugenja Spell Progression**
>
> The shugenja’s spell progression
> chart is misaligned. The 8th-level and 9th-level columns should shift
> down two levels (with 8th-level spells becoming available at 16th
> level and 9th-level spells at 18th level).

### If you can live without 9th level spells

The **Divine Bard** variant class from Unearthed Arcana, p50. Basically:

> A divine bard learns and casts spells as a normal bard, with some minor exceptions. A divine bard's spells are divine spells, not arcane spells.

The **Nightstalker** from the Dragonlance (licensed non-WotC) book Races of Ansalon, p153. It relies on Charisma for everything except Bonus Spells, but if your DM allows Dragonlance material, then you can get the **Dynamic Priest feat** from Legends of the Twins to fix that:

> **Benefit:** For the purpose of determining bonus divine spells per day and maximum divine spell level, your primary spellcasting ability is Charisma. If you have more than one divine spellcasting class, the bonus applies to only one of those classes. Your spell save DCs are not affected by this change.

Comment: You may want to mention Dynamic Priest for the favored soul, as well. (+1 either way, just an idea.)

Comment: @KRyan Hang on...Dynamic Priest affects Bonus Spells and maximum spell level, but not DCs, and DCs are the problem with Favored Soul, right?

Comment: I can never remember which is which. I guess it was spirit shaman it would fix.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to the favored soul and shugenja mentioned in [From’s fine answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/203537/4563), *Complete Divine* also has the spirit shaman that is kind of like the reverse of the favored soul here: Wisdom for minimum-to-learn and bonus spells, Charisma for DCs. The spirit shaman uses a unique form of spellcasting, where they “retrieve” certain divine spells each morning, which is basically as if you got to prepare your spells known each morning as a spontaneous spellcaster. The spirit shaman uses the druid spell list.

Unfortunately, all three of favored soul, shugenja, and spirit shaman leave a fair bit to be desired, compared to cleric or druid, or sorcerer for that matter. They are all “full” spellcasters, they get to 9th-level spells, so they’re definitely not weak, but the other class features of the favored soul and spirit shaman are quite poor, and the shugenja spell list is not nearly as good as the cleric or druid spell list.

Also worth mentioning here is the divine crusader prestige class, **also** from *Complete Divine*. That’s all-Charisma, and even gets 9th-level spells in just 9 levels (!). On the other hand, a divine crusader’s spell list is **just one domain**. Choose wisely. A very neat class, though; fits very well with divine feats if you can find a source of turn undead.

Finally, we have the sha’ir from *Dragon Compendium*. This is an **extremely** weird class, that sends a tiny genie off to collect spells from the Elemental Planes (somehow). It’s not properly prepared and it’s not properly spontaneous, but instead you get each spell individually which can take a few rounds to a few hours depending on which you get, and then that spell has to be cast within the next couple of hours (rather than being prepared for the whole day). But it is purely Charisma-based, and it is **both arcane and divine**. The sha’ir uses the sorcerer/wizard spell list, plus nine domains (Air, Chaos, Earth, Fire, Knowledge, Law, Luck, Sun, and Water)—and the sha’ir actually casts the spells from those domains as divine spells. It’s a weird system; kinda neat though. Plus no one with access to the full sor/wiz spell list is hurting for power.

Comment: The Sha'ir is definitely the strongest option of those currently proposed by me and KRyan. In most attempts to tier base classes, it ends up in the top tier. It is a bit weird and doesn't have a lot of splatbook love, but 9th level sor/wiz arcane casting + 9 domains divine? Top tier. Also qualifies it for a lot of prestige classes, including some theurges...Sha'ir 3/Cloistered Cleric 1/Mystic Theurge 10/Geomancer 6 leaves you...*cough*..."perfectly balanced, as all things should be". And very SAD.

Comment: @From I don't think that I've ever seen a version of [Why Each Class Is In Its Tier](https://forums.giantitp.com/showthread.php?269440-Why-Each-Class-Is-In-Its-Tier-(Rescued-from-MinMax)) that includes it.

Comment: @J.Mini Here's one: https://forums.giantitp.com/showthread.php?568771-Retiering-the-Classes-A-new-home

Comment: @From A shame that there's no "Why" document for that list. To find explanations, you would have to read each thread individually. Still, great resource.